# Removing cycles from graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Assume I have a connected undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, I want to find a smallest subset of $E$ to remove so that all cycles are removed.

From the Wikipedia page on [circuit rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_rank), if I understand right, the following approach works: Find an arbitrary cycle in $G$, remove any edge of the cycle, and repeat. Is there a simple way to prove that this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the circuit rank of a finite graph $G=(V,E)$ as $r(G)=|E|-|V|+c$ where $c$ is the number of connected components of $G$.  Note that a connected graph $G$ has $r(G)\geq 0$ and $r(G)=0$ iff $G$ is a tree.  Moreover, if the connected components of $G$ are $G_1,\dots,G_n$, then $r(G)=\sum_{i=1}^n r(G_i)$.  It follows that $r(G)=0$ iff $G$ is a forest, i.e. $G$ has no cycles.

Now consider what happens when you remove an edge from a graph $G$.  If that edge is part of a cycle, you decrease $|E|$ by $1$ but do not change $|V|$ or $c$, so $r(G)$ decreases by $1$.  If the edge is not part of a cycle, you additionally increase $c$ by $1$ (since you split a component in two), so $r(G)$ does not change.

So, if you want to decrease $r(G)$ down to $0$ by removing as few edges as possible, you should always remove edges that are part of a cycle, and it will take $r(G)$ steps.